# Where can I find a system architecture for a site that will stream music for thousands of concurrent users?

Tags: architecture, scalability

Does anyone know where I can find a system architecture for a site that streams music for thousands of concurrent users and can also scale.  Also I would prefer to use open source system components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by reading about popular open source projects like Darwin, [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/), [FFserver](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver-doc.html), Helix, [Catra Streaming Platform](http://www.catrasoftware.it/Streaming/CatraStreamingPlatform.htm), [LScube](http://live.polito.it/) and of course [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/). HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I found the book [Building Scalable Web Sites: Building, scaling, and optimizing the next generation of web applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102356) by Cal Henderson, the architect of Flickr, to be a good overview issues involved with scaling a site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [gstreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/). It has a plugin based architecture that allows you to only load what you need but it can adapt easily to future changes. You can even do transcoding and filtering with it however for thousands of simultaneous streams I'd avoid adding extra processing.